# Linking 2 tables in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database containing 2 tables - "db" and "details".

On clicking a particular field in db column ('Issued to') of any record in the "db" table I want to display all the fields of the "details" table matching with the particular column "Issued to" in "details" table.

In my code the page shows all the matching results of both the tables.

I just want the selected (clicked on) record result.

The code is as follows-

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = "";
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
     $sql = 'SELECT a.`Issued to`, b.Name, b.DOB, b.Discipline, b.Designation, b.PlaceOfPosting, b.PhoneNo, b.Email
        FROM db a, details b
        WHERE a.`Issued to` = b.`Issued to`';

    mysql_select_db('testdb');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
         echo "Name:{$row['Name']}  <br> ".
         "Date Of Birth:{$row['DOB']}  <br> ".
         "Discipline:{$row['Discipline']}  <br> ".
         "Designation:{$row['Designation']}  <br> ".
         "Place of Posting:{$row['PlaceOfPosting']}  <br> ".
         "Phone: {$row['PhoneNo']} <br> ".
         "Email Id: {$row['Email']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
    } 
    mysql_close($conn);
   ?>
```

Comment: add AND condition to your WHERE clause `AND a.`Issued to` = <value of the clicked field>`

Comment: Warning (mysql) -> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

change to below condition :

```
  WHERE a.`Issued to` = b.`Issued to` and a.`Issued to`=<variablehere>';
```

get the variable from $_POST OR $_GET basic on what method are you using.

> **Warning** *(mysql) -> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it
>   was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension
>   should be used.*